# How to create KSQL table from a topic with composite key?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I have some topic data with the fields `stringA` `stringB` and I am just trying to use that as the key when creating a KSQL table from a topic.

Answer (score 3):

Just an update to @Robin Moffat..
Use the below

```
CREATE STREAM TEST_REKEY AS 
        SELECT STRINGA + STRINGB AS MY_COMPOSITE_KEY, 
               STRINGA, 
               STRINGB, 
               COL3 
          FROM TEST 
          PARTITION BY STRINGA + STRINGB ;
```

instead of

```
CREATE STREAM TEST_REKEY AS 
        SELECT STRINGA + STRINGB AS MY_COMPOSITE_KEY, 
               STRINGA, 
               STRINGB, 
               COL3 
          FROM TEST 
          PARTITION BY MY_COMPOSITE_KEY ;
```

**NOTE: column ordering matters**
Worked for me! (CLI v0.10.1, Server v0.10.1)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example. First, I'll create and populate a test stream

```sql
ksql> CREATE STREAM TEST (STRINGA VARCHAR, 
                          STRINGB VARCHAR, 
                          COL3 INT) 
                    WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='TEST',
                          PARTITIONS=1,
                          VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------

ksql> INSERT INTO TEST (STRINGA, STRINGB, COL3) VALUES ('A','B',1);
ksql> INSERT INTO TEST (STRINGA, STRINGB, COL3) VALUES ('A','B',2);
ksql> INSERT INTO TEST (STRINGA, STRINGB, COL3) VALUES ('C','D',3);
ksql>
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' to 'earliest'. Use the UNSET command to revert your change.

ksql> SELECT * FROM TEST EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 3;
+--------------+--------+---------+----------+------+
|ROWTIME       |ROWKEY  |STRINGA  |STRINGB   |COL3  |
+--------------+--------+---------+----------+------+
|1578569329184 |null    |A        |B         |1     |
|1578569331653 |null    |A        |B         |2     |
|1578569339177 |null    |C        |D         |3     |
```

Note that `ROWKEY` is null.

Now I'll create a new stream, populated from the first, and create the composite column set it as the key. I'm also including the original fields themselves, but this is optional if you don't need them:

```sql
ksql> CREATE STREAM TEST_REKEY AS 
        SELECT STRINGA + STRINGB AS MY_COMPOSITE_KEY, 
               STRINGA, 
               STRINGB, 
               COL3 
          FROM TEST 
          PARTITION BY MY_COMPOSITE_KEY ;

 Message
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Stream TEST_REKEY created and running. Created by query with query ID: CSAS_TEST_REKEY_9
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now you have a stream of data with the key set to your composite key:

```sql
ksql> SELECT ROWKEY , COL3 FROM TEST_REKEY EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 3;
+---------+-------+
|ROWKEY   |COL3   |
+---------+-------+
|AB       |1      |
|AB       |2      |
|CD       |3      |
Limit Reached
Query terminated
```

You can also inspect the underlying Kafka topic to verify the key:

```sql
ksql> PRINT TEST_REKEY LIMIT 3;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1578569329184,"ROWKEY":"AB","MY_COMPOSITE_KEY":"AB","STRINGA":"A","STRINGB":"B","COL3":1}
{"ROWTIME":1578569331653,"ROWKEY":"AB","MY_COMPOSITE_KEY":"AB","STRINGA":"A","STRINGB":"B","COL3":2}
{"ROWTIME":1578569339177,"ROWKEY":"CD","MY_COMPOSITE_KEY":"CD","STRINGA":"C","STRINGB":"D","COL3":3}
ksql>
```

With this done, we can now declare a table on top of the re-keyed topic:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (ROWKEY VARCHAR KEY, 
                         COL3 INT) 
    WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='TEST_REKEY', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

From this table we can query the state. Note that the composite key `AB` only shows the latest value, which is part of the semantics of a table (compare to the stream above, in which you see both values - both stream and table are the same Kafka topic):

```
ksql> SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE EMIT CHANGES;
+----------------+---------+------+
|ROWTIME         |ROWKEY   |COL3  |
+----------------+---------+------+
|1578569331653   |AB       |2     |
|1578569339177   |CD       |3     |
```

Comment: I get an error that the composite key can't be resolved when I try this:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM myevents_rekey
>    WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='myevents_rekey')  AS
>    SELECT myId + '#' + myExternalId as COMPOSITE_KEY
>    FROM myevents
>    PARTITION BY COMPOSITE_KEY;
Line: 5, Col: 18: PARTITION BY column 'COMPOSITE_KEY' cannot be resolved.
```
Any ideas about this?

Comment: Please start a new question, referencing this one.

Comment: I wonder if this answer is still relevant because when I try to use fields created in the qyery I now get " MY_COMPOSITE_KEY  must be a column in the source schema since PARTITION BY is applied on the input." . So is it possible today to use 2 or more columns for partitioning the stream ?

Comment: ksqlDB will have changed a lot in 2+ years, and as a pre-1.0 release will sometimes have breaking changes. I suggest going to confluent.io/community/ask-the-community to get the latest answer to this.

Comment: @SeB.Fr, I ran into that too, but this worked for me:

`
CREATE STREAM repartitioned_stream AS
   SELECT * FROM my_stream
   PARTITION BY STRUCT(K1 := <expression 1>, K2 := <expression 2>)
   EMIT CHANGES;
`

Further info: https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksqldb-0-15-reads-more-message-keys-supports-more-data-types/#join-on-sources